# Password Reset Email delay

Tags: magento2.4.3

New to Magento and while I understand that customers need to reset passwords after importing. I would like to wait on sending the email for a few hours or a day. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes via cron.

First, create a simple module and add crontab.xml and the class which will be called via cron.

Add your code to send an email to reset the password.

Comment: wait, so does the email automatically send when importing the customers or is that something I have to do?

Comment: I think you don't know How cron works

Comment: I do. I just want to know if I decide to import my customers into my new site without a cron job. Will an email send?

Comment: I don't think so unless you have written some code or added some configuration setting in admin.